# Why was Barry Gibb's and Michael Jackson's "All In Your Name" song released 9 years after being recorded and after Michael Jackson's death?

Tags: history, pop, release, michael-jackson

Barry Gibb's and Michael Jackson's "[All In Your Name](https://youtu.be/KkvmKpuQGR0)" song was released 9 years after being recorded and after Michael Jackson's death. Why?